# Fetch All Records Between Latests Dates Group By ID

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Let's say I have a table like below:

| id | start_value | end_value | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 05-APR-23 | 2 |
| 1 | null | 5 | 09-APR-23 | null |
| 1 | 5 | null | 15-APR-23 | null |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | 4 |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -1 |
| 1 | null | 8 | 16-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | 1 | null | 05-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | null | 9 | 09-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | 9 | null | 13-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | null | null | 13-APR-23 | 1 |
| 2 | null | null | 14-APR-23 | -5 |
| 2 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | -3 |
| 2 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -4 |
| 2 | null | -1 | 16-APR-23 | null |

I asked [a question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047069/oracle-latest-values-group-by-id) and can get the latest non-null start and end values for an id like below with SQL:

```
SELECT id,
       start_value,
       end_value,
       start_date,
       end_date
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         LAST_VALUE(start_value)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS start_value,
         LAST_VALUE(end_value)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS end_value,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN start_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS start_date,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN end_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS end_date,
         ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

| id | start_value | end_value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 | 15-APR-23 | 16-APR-23 |
| 2 | 9 | -1 | 13-APR-23 | 16-APR-23 |

Now, I would like to get the intermediate values between the latest non null start and end dates for an ID like below, but couldn't figure it out how to do that:

| id | start_value | end_value | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | null | 15-APR-23 | null |
| 1 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | 4 |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -1 |
| 1 | null | 8 | 16-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | 9 | null | 13-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | null | null | 13-APR-23 | 1 |
| 2 | null | null | 14-APR-23 | -5 |
| 2 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | -3 |
| 2 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -4 |
| 2 | null | -1 | 16-APR-23 | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `LAST_VALUE` for start and end date with a window over the entire result set and then filter on that:

```sql
SELECT id,
       start_value,
       end_value,
       "DATE",
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN start_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (
              PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE"
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) AS start_date,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN end_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (
              PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE"
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) AS end_date
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  "DATE" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, start_value, end_value, "DATE", value) AS
SELECT 1, null, null, DATE '2023-04-05', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, null, 5,    DATE '2023-04-09', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5,    null, DATE '2023-04-15', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, null, null, DATE '2023-04-16', -4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, null, null, DATE '2023-04-16', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, null, 8,    DATE '2023-04-16', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,    null, DATE '2023-04-05', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, 9,    DATE '2023-04-09', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 9,    null, DATE '2023-04-13', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, null, DATE '2023-04-13', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, null, DATE '2023-04-14', -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, null, DATE '2023-04-15', -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, null, DATE '2023-04-16', -4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, null, -1,   DATE '2023-04-16', null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | START_VALUE | END_VALUE | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | *null* | 2023-04-15 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | -4 |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | -1 |
| 1 | *null* | 8 | 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2 | 9 | *null* | 2023-04-13 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-13 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-14 00:00:00 | -5 |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-15 00:00:00 | -3 |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | -4 |
| 2 | *null* | -1 | 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g64jOk5j)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of non-null start_value values for each id, then use `DENSE_RANK` to rank your counts per id. Once you have that, you can use rank = 1 in the same fashion of your previous post.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tab.*, 
           COUNT(start_value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_) AS cnt
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn 
    FROM cte
)
SELECT id,
       start_value,
       end_value,
       date_,
       value_
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id, date_, start_value, value_, end_value
```

**Output**:

| ID | START_VALUE | END_VALUE | DATE_ | VALUE_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | null | 15-APR-23 | null |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -1 |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | 4 |
| 1 | null | 8 | 16-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | 9 | null | 13-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | null | null | 13-APR-23 | 1 |
| 2 | null | null | 14-APR-23 | -5 |
| 2 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | -3 |
| 2 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -4 |
| 2 | null | -1 | 16-APR-23 | null |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3f5Bw8Du).

---

If you don't mind the order of the output rows, another option is using `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES` clause.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tab.*, 
           COUNT(start_value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_) AS cnt
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id,
       start_value,
       end_value,
       date_,
       value_
FROM cte
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cnt DESC) = 1 THEN 1 END
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using your query that get latest non-null start and end values in a `cte` then join it to your table as follows :

```
  with cte as (
  SELECT id,
       start_value,
       end_value,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       value
  FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         LAST_VALUE(start_value)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS start_value,
         LAST_VALUE(end_value)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS end_value,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN start_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS start_date,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN end_value IS NOT NULL THEN "DATE" END)
            IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE") AS end_date,
         ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" DESC) AS rn,
        value
  FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
select t.*
from table_name t
inner join cte c on t.id = c.id and T."DATE" between start_date AND end_date;
```

Result :

| id | start_value | end_value | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | null | 15-APR-23 | null |
| 1 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | 4 |
| 1 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -1 |
| 1 | null | 8 | 16-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | 9 | null | 13-APR-23 | null |
| 2 | null | null | 13-APR-23 | 1 |
| 2 | null | null | 14-APR-23 | -5 |
| 2 | null | null | 15-APR-23 | -3 |
| 2 | null | null | 16-APR-23 | -4 |
| 2 | null | -1 | 16-APR-23 | null |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ODGTtfl)